# Adding tags to identify notes in a django website?

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently working on a django project where you can upload course materials, have a personal calendar with notes and a to-do list. I am working on the notes and a personal feature I would like to add is I would either like to be able to attach the notes to a class, or I would like to be able to add identifying tags that would group the notes. Maybe even make it so that when they "enroll" in a paticular class, it automatically creates a folder for that class for them to add notes to. Could anyone shed some light on possible ways I could accomplish this?

So far, I only have the ability to create notes, edit and delete them.